# Tense selection in a comparative sentence where the reference is an ongoing process in the past

Tags: tense

Which of the following is correct?

1. I woke up earlier today than I **had been** over the past six months.
2. I woke up earlier today than I **had** over the past six months.
3. I woke up earlier today than I **did** over the past six months.

I would appreciate it if you could explain the reason by providing the underlying full sentence, for example:

> I choose option 1 because it is a shorthand for the full sentence *"I woke up earlier
> today than I **had been** waking up over the past six months."*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All three of your options are grammatically correct, and possibly have the meaning you want. One has a slightly different meaning than the other two. There's also a fourth option that I'd  prefer. I'll explain all four.

> 1. I woke up earlier today than I **had been** over the past six months.

As you say, this has the underlying clause, "*I **had been waking** up*". The continuous aspect suggests this is a *general pattern* rather than an *unbroken streak* of wake-up times. In other words, past perfect continuous is the correct choice if there was a general pattern of getting up later, and that pattern ended today.

> 2. I woke up earlier today than I **had** over the past six months.
> 3. I woke up earlier today than I **did** over the past six months.

These two have the same meaning. It's already clear from the context that "today" happened after "the past six months", so it's up to the writer whether to use grammar to also make this clear. Both sentences suggest an *unbroken streak* of waking up later than today, so either tense would be appropriate when talking about something that's clearly in the past.

The best choice might be a fourth option:

> 4. I woke up earlier to day than I **have been** over the past six months.

This also implies the continuous, "*I have been waking up*", which again suggests a *general pattern* of wake-up times, rather than an *unbroken streak*. The present tense indicates that the general pattern is still true now, despite not having followed it today. In most contexts, waking up once earlier than normal isn't enough to consider a pattern of wake-up times disrupted. So without a more constrained context -- like today is the first day at a new job where you have to wake up earlier than normal -- this version with present perfect is probably going to be the best.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation! I really appreciate it! 

You suggested that present perfect is preferred over past perfect. I have a question related to this. It is common to say that present perfect refers to a process that started in the past and **continues until the present**. In the above example, the process of "waking up late" was actually terminated today; i.e., it did not really continue until the present. Am I missing anything?

Thank you very much, again!

Comment: @HD In that case, you're right, #1 is the best answer. I've edited my explanation of #1 to be clearer about that and to remove my incorrect assumptions

Comment: Thank you very much. It was helpful! I have another follow-up question if you don't mind. You talked about two notions in your response. (i) General pattern and (ii) Unbroken streak. I am not sure how these two notions are exactly different in the context above. In the above example, the reference time period is the last 6X30=180 days. I woke up late on each and every one of those 180 days. But I changed course and woke up early today. I plan to continue waking up early from now on. Please do not hesitate to let me know if more information is needed.

Comment: @HD If you woke up late every single day, then woke up earlier today, then you're describing an unbroken streak, in which case any of your answers is correct, but not mine. The first is correct too because an unbroken streak is also a pattern.

Comment: Thank you. It seems like the difference between an unbroken streak and a pattern is that the former may break at any time but the latter occurs consistently and reliably. Did I get it right? Thank you for all your valuable help! 

Comment: @HD The opposite (or you got "former" and "latter" mixed up). A streak is a consecutive series. A pattern is repeats at a regular interval. So, an unbroken streak means for 180 days in a row, you got up late, while a pattern means for 180 days you usually (or always) got up late.

Comment: Thank you for the info. Got it. I am glad I asked!

Comment: I wanted to ask another question about your original response if you don't mind. In your response, you mentioned "it's up to the writer whether to use grammar to also make this clear". Just to make sure, you meant that both "simple past" (i.e., did) and "past perfect" (i.e., had) will work, because even if one uses simple past, it is clear that the events over the past six months occurred earlier than _today morning_. So there will be no confusion if one uses simple past instead of past perfect. Did I get your message right?

Comment: @HD That's correct

Answer (score 0):

The Main Grammar Point Here:
If you have a comparative, you do not need to repeat the main verb after the comparative clause (for example, I woke up **earlier than**), it is enough to use the auxiliary. That is the grammar teaching point here.

I woke up earlier today than I had over the past six months.

I woke earlier today and had woken up earlier over the past six months, as well.

**If you join those two comparatively, you get your first sentence.**

In your sentence, the **woken** after *had* is implied.

However, *it could also be stated like this*:

I woke up earlier today than I had woken up over the past six months.

The same goes for this:

I woke up earlier today and I also woke up earlier over the past six months.

I woke up earlier today than I *did* over the past six months.

Comparatives do not require repetition of the main verb. The auxiliary is enough.

In this one: I woke up earlier today than I had been over the past six months.

That reads as: I woke up earlier today than I had been [waking up] over the past six months.

Again, the auxiliary is enough. In this case, *had been* is used as it is preceded by a simple past.

to wake, woke, woken

- be waking up, which is a progressive form.
- past perfect of that one is: had been waking up

All three sample sentences are correct.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. To provide more context, I woke up pretty late over the past six months. So It is *not* the case I woke up early BOTH today and over the last six months. Please let me know if the context requires more clarification.

Comment: @HD I'm afraid you've lost me. My main point is this: In comparatives, you do not need to restate the main verb. It is enough to use the auxiliary after the adjective + than. I showed that already so I feel my job is done. And it seems to me you chose an answer that does not explain **that fact**.

Comment: Thank you for your message. I am aware that the usage of an auxiliary is enough in the second part of comparatives. I tried to follow this rule in the three examples provided in the original question numbered 1 to 3. Please let me know if I am missing anything.

Comment: @HD If you are aware of this, what then is your question?? I  gave you the full "underlying sentence" for each one and a rule that governs it. You accepted the other answer that does not do this at all. Cheers.

Comment: My question was about "tense selection". In particular, I wasn't sure whether to use _simple past_, _past perfect_, or _past perfect continuous_. (I tried to reflect on the gist of my question in the question title.)

Comment: @HD  I **wake** up earlier now than I **had been** (waking up) in the past. It seems to me that you asked and answered your own question. Like I said, all of them are correct. **The tense depends on what *you want to say*.**